# How to convert string dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm int0 datetime format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string value like "26-APR-2019 16:40". I want to convert this in to date time in java script. Please help me.

Comment: This datetime string format is not supported. You'll have to split the string into it's parts yourself. And convert APR into a valid month name some way.

Comment: I recommend you to use moment.js    https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Where are you getting the string? If possible, fix the source to pass a valid date for JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) function to parse your string into a date object. Your string is not compatible with this function you will have to parse the sting manually with some switch case operations.